# The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client

Tags: oracle

Preciso de uma ajuda, pois estou tentando executar um serviço do windows no Visual Studio 2015, porém não consigo prosseguir devido à mensagem de erro "The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client".

Obrigado.

Comment: Qual a versão do seu Client do Oracle da sua máquina?

Comment: Olá David, versão 11.2.0.1.0 .

Answer (score 2):

Cesar, não tenho certeza, mas acho tenha que instalar **Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015**, dentro da instalação tem o provider, do qual está reclamando da compatibilidade.

[Data Access Components (ODAC) 
with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html)

Olhe também essa resposta no SOen:
[Managed ODP.NET driver does not show up in Data Source dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694919/managed-odp-net-driver-does-not-show-up-in-data-source-dialog)

Espero que ajude.